# How to open <select> when image is overlapped

Tags: javascript, html, dom, z-index

I am trying to overlap an image in front of a HTML  element, so that I can simulate having a different arrow icon. I successfully achieved that, however even though I am able to click on the "text" area of the selector, obviously nothing happens if I click on top of the custom image (since it sits on top of the  and is unrelated to it). I need to make it work for IE10 only, although I tried in Chrome and doesn't work either.

I did some research and seems like attaching some JS to the image to open the selector options is hard, if not impossible, specially for IE. As a separate effort, I tried setting a lower z-index for the image node, so that the mouse click event would ignore the image and go straight to the  node, but didn't work. I wanted to check if anybody would have another idea, or if it's actually impossible to achieve.

Here is the fiddle for my code. For simplicity, I have replaced the image URL for just `background-color: red`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaara_sama/mdsLF/)

Here is the full code:

```
<style type="text/css">

.styled-select {
   width: 240px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
}

.styled-select select {
   width: 268px;
   z-index: 5;
   background-color: transparent;
}

.imageNode {
   background-color: red;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   top: 2px;
   height: 32px;
   width: 32px;
   overflow: hidden;
   z-index: 3;
}

</style>



<div class="styled-select">
   <select>
      <option>Here is the first option!!!!!!!!!!</option>
      <option>The second option</option>
      <option>Third option!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</option>
   </select>

   <div class="imageNode"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So many exclamation marks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: These are always a problem. There are good xbrowser solutions. http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/ is a good one, and jQuery UI.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure if we want to have a whole library just for this functionality, but might be the only solution. I will check this out!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `CSS :after` pseudo element

html

```
<div class="custom-select">
<select>
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
<option>c</option>
</select>
</div>
```

css

```
div.custom-select {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
  }

.custom-select select {
display: inline-block;
padding: 4px 3px 3px 5px;
margin: 0;
font: inherit;
outline:none; /* remove focus ring from Webkit */
line-height: 1.2;
background: #000;
color:white;
border:0;
}

/* Select arrow styling */
.custom-select:after {
content: "▼";  /* Current arrow I would like to change */
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
font-size: 60%;
line-height: 30px;
padding: 0 7px;
background: #000;
color: white;
}

.no-pointer-events .custom-select:after {
content: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I tried this on jsfiddle (both chrome and IE10) and did not work. The challenge is to click on the arrow and make the options open.

Also, the arrow must be an image (in my provided example, it is the red square).